# Latex does not update the pdf viewer

Tags: texmaker

I am trying to write my report in Texmaker and so when I try to use the quickbuild  function, it shows the same old pdf in the latex inbuilt viewer. I have already tried changing all the options in the configure texmaker settings after referring different posts for the same problem and also tried reinstalling texmaker but it doesn't solve my problem. And also there are only 2 files updated, the latex and text file. There is no log file generated. Please help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by reinstalling the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now successfully compile and view the output in Texmaker. I think it was not installed properly since there were previous files related to texmaker in my system. then I searched and deleted  for all the files related to texmaker and also miktex. So now after reinstallation, it works perfectly fine. Also I turned off the firewall. Hope it helps to some other people too! :)